# Javascript - Pull Table Row text only for IF comparison

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, row

I have been trying to get this to work for hours. I am so close but the answer still eludes me. I am new to Javascript. I have found similar posts but I am unable to get those integrated. I really need help.

I am attempting to take data from 1 row from a table of 50 rows. I then need to look at that row and if there is an "N" then it won't pull other data.

The problem I am having is, I am unable to pull an entire row that is free from HTML code so I can use it in comparison. Its either that or take "x" and look see if part of the string matches. Grateful for any help you can provide.

**1 Table Row**
        
          168 Some Text
          111-0000-00-333
          Y
          Y
          Y
          N
          N
          N
          Y
          Y
          Y

**HTML Page Follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction1()
{
/*
var x = document.getElementById("row1").innerHTML;
*/

var 

x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[3].firstChild.innerHTML;  

var y="168 Some Text";
var z="";
if (x==y)
  {
  z="Match";
  }
  else
  {
  z="No Match";
  } 
document.write(x);
document.write(y);
document.write(z);
}
</script>
```

**Not sure the following is pertinant to our discussion.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($)

    {

    $('#resultA').load('DataTableUpdate.html #myTable');

    });


    </script>
    <p id="resultA"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Pretty easy fix. Instead of .innerHTML I changed it to .innerText. Now its just pulling just text. I thought I tried that before but who knows why it didn't work before.